# Combine similar columns with different character names data?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

```
ID <- c("IDa", "IDb","IDc","IDe","IDd","IDe")
names1 <- c("robin", "bob", "eric", "charlie", "robin", "gabby")
matrix1 <- matrix(names1, 1, 6)
colnames(matrix1) <- c("IDa", "IDb", "IDc","IDe", "IDd", "IDe")
```

This is the output:

| IDa | IDb | IDc | IDe | IDd | IDe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| robin | bob | eric | charlie | robin | gabby |

But I want it to look like this:

| IDa | IDb | IDc | IDe | IDd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| robin | bob | eric | charlie | robin |
|  |  |  | gabby |  |

Comment: Side note: it's generally not a good idea to name objects after common base functions such as `names` and `matrix`.

Comment: You tagged [tag:dataframe] but you create a `matrix`. If you need it to be a `data.frame` in the end, you should probably be explicit about that.

Comment: In addition to @r2evans' comment, also `names` is a reserved name. Get in the habit of using e.g. `?names` to check if the name is already used elsewhere!

Answer (score 3):

We may `split` and then `cbind` after padding with `NA`

```
lst1 <- split(names, ID)
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
```

-output

```
     IDa     IDb   IDc    IDd     IDe      
[1,] "robin" "bob" "eric" "robin" "charlie"
[2,] NA      NA    NA     NA      "gabby"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

melt(matrix1) %>% 
  select(-Var1) %>% 
  group_by(Var2) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Var2,
    values_from = value
  ) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
  IDa   IDb   IDc   IDe     IDd  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>
1 robin bob   eric  charlie robin
2 NA    NA    NA    gabby   NA
```